# Truncate text from middle in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hy, I am using material Ui in my React app and trying to truncate text from the middle.
i searched a lot and tried different methods by adding classes like  `wordWrap: 'break-word'` but nothing works for me.

i have token:

```
0x3b3ch76c99f02o8k29aef20
```

and want to show it like this:

```
0x3b3c...aef20
```

i tried this: `{token.substring(0, 5) + "..." + token.substring(20, 25)}` it work but it does not seem generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this generic by using the `length` of the string

```js
const formatToken = (token) => {
  return `${token.slice(0, 6)}...${token.slice(
    token.length - 6,
    token.length
  )}`;
};

const formattedToken = formatToken("0x3b3ch76c99f02o8k29aef20")
// returns 0x3b3c...9aef20
```